# Find the area (hyperbola)

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

Find the area between the equilateral hyperbola $ x^2 - y^2 = 9$ , the x-axis and the **diameter passing through the point (5,4)**

I couldn't figure out what is this diameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **diameter** of a hyperbola is any line that passes through the centre of the hyperbola, in this case the origin.

The line through the origin and $(5,4)$ has equation $y=\frac{4}{5}x$.